# Setup for several origins for a WMTS in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, wmts

I´m trying to setup a map with a WMTS as a layer with help form this example: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/wmts.html

The layer works fine for the first three levels, but after the third, the layer get an offset.

If i look into my GetCapabilities I can see that the first three levels has the same "TopLeftCorner". But in the fourth, the value changes.

From:

```
<TopLeftCorner>6445536 95000</TopLeftCorner>
```

To:

```
<TopLeftCorner>6441440 95000</TopLeftCorner>
```

This also happens for level 5, 7 and 8, where the value changes.

As i´m using:  `origin: ol.extent.getTopLeft(projectionExtent)` the value is constant on `95000, 6445536`, which make me belive thats why I get an offset.

Is it possible to use more than one set of x & y-values for the `origin` depending on the resolution? Or any other way to get around this problem? (not the GetCapabilities-example).

Comment: Yes, both `ol.tilegrid.TileGrid` and `ol.tilegrid.WMTS` can take either one `origin` or an `origins` array (one for each zoom level)

Comment: Above comment is actually the answer.

Comment: Okey, sounds good! Any example of how to do it?